# Alarm manager executing after every app lauch instead of set period

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've set an alarm manager to download web content every 24h at 10:40am but apart from executing at proper time, apparently it launches few seconds after successfully running the app. I want this to run exclusively at the set time.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value-stores/3Po6TV7wTht4vIEid/records/LATEST?disableRedirect=true");
        String contentText = "Nowe zakażenia: " +infectionsInfo+ " Nowe śmierci: "+deathsInfo;



        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notifyLemubit1")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.unnamed)
                .setContentTitle("Punkty zostały przyznane!")
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(200, builder.build());
```

and

````
        calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE,40);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, PointsBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MenuActivity.this, 0, intent1, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent1);```
````

Answer (score 0):

All repeating alarms are **inexact** in order not to easily let developers abuse them.

If you want the action to be done in that exact time you need to use one-time alarms. To make them "repeating" you need to schedule the first one initially and always schedule the next one once the alarm is fired.

Although your issue might be due to this plus some other issue.

Exact alarms should only be used for extremely important tasks so I suggest considering using WorkManager so you don't affect the battery of the device as much.